# How do we extract the list from a string that contains a list which contains 4-5 dictioaries?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a data representation which looks like below and when importing in pandas, it is converting it into a string. By this, I'm unable to treat the value as a list to perform any further action. A sample of the data is given below :

```
pck_details = ['[{"k1":"val1","k2":"val2","k3":"val3"},
                 {"k4":"val4","k5":"val5","k6":"val6"}]',
               '[{"k1":"val1","k2":"val2","k3":"val3"},
                 {"k4":"val4","k5":"val5","k6":"val6"}]',
               '[{"k1":"val1","k2":"val2","k3":"val3"},
                 {"k4":"val4","k5":"val5","k6":"val6"}]',
               '[{"k1":"val1","k2":"val2","k3":"val3"},
                 {"k4":"val4","k5":"val5","k6":"val6"}]'

              ]
```

I have tried using the below one for one element, let's say

```
pck1 = pck_details[0]
pck.strip('][').split(",")
```

but this is now treating legit dictionary inside the list as a set of strings and I am back to the string problem again. So how do I get my list of dictionaries properly from being a string?

```
input -> '[{"k1":"val1","k2":"val2","k3":"val3"},
                 {"k1":"val1","k2":"val2","k3":"val3"}]'
(which is a string)

output -> [{"k1":"val1","k2":"val2","k3":"val3"},
                 {"k1":"val1","k2":"val2","k3":"val3"}]
(which is a list)
```

Comment: Try looking into json.loads

Comment: What is source of `str` inside your `pck_details`?

Answer (score 1):

**`json.loads`** will help.

```
import json

pck_details = ['[{"k1":"val1","k2":"val2","k3":"val3"},{"k4":"val4","k5":"val5","k6":"val6"}]',
               '[{"k1":"val1","k2":"val2","k3":"val3"},{"k4":"val4","k5":"val5","k6":"val6"}]',
               '[{"k1":"val1","k2":"val2","k3":"val3"},{"k4":"val4","k5":"val5","k6":"val6"}]',
               '[{"k1":"val1","k2":"val2","k3":"val3"},{"k4":"val4","k5":"val5","k6":"val6"}]'
               ]
for item in pck_details:
    print(json.loads(item))
```

it'll give you the following output.

```
[{'k1': 'val1', 'k2': 'val2', 'k3': 'val3'}, {'k4': 'val4', 'k5': 'val5', 'k6': 'val6'}] 
[{'k1': 'val1', 'k2': 'val2', 'k3': 'val3'}, {'k4': 'val4', 'k5': 'val5', 'k6': 'val6'}] 
[{'k1': 'val1', 'k2': 'val2', 'k3': 'val3'}, {'k4': 'val4', 'k5': 'val5', 'k6': 'val6'}] 
[{'k1': 'val1', 'k2': 'val2', 'k3': 'val3'}, {'k4': 'val4', 'k5': 'val5', 'k6': 'val6'}]
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

ast can help:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval('{"A":"qwerty"')
{"A":"qwerty"}
```